# Python - Como transformo esse código em uma função usando return?

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer uma função para imprimir os títulos //'PLACA', 'MODELO', 'VALOR'// de forma tabulada, mas ainda não sei utilizar o return de forma correta. Esse projeto é para adquirir conhecimento. Como esse bloco de códigos pode ser transformado em uma função que retorne os títulos dessa forma? PLACA     MODELO     VALOR
Qual seria a sintaxe correta?

```
def imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL):

        return = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(PL,MD,VL))
        titulos = imprimir_placa('PLACA', 'MODELO', 'VALOR')
        print(titulos)

imprimir_placa()
```

Comment: Segundo o seu histórico de perguntas esse é código aparentemente é referente a um mesmo software usando a lib *pandas*. Se não dá mais detalhes de seu cenário, mesmo que bem intencionados os autores de respostas poderão não oferecer as melhores e mais eficientes respostas por os faltar informação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que você pretende, mas já que é para estudo vou tentar dar uma explicação simples.

Quando você cria uma função

> def imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL):

Você está dizendo que quando ela for chamada, ela irá receber os valores que você colocou nos parâmetros dela, mas nesse caso você não passa nada nos parâmetros, até porque essas variáveis PL, MD, VL ainda nem existem.

Outra coisa é que você não precisa do **return** para esse código funcionar, pois a sua função já está cumprindo a ação que deveria, que é imprimir as variáveis de maneira tabulada, o **return** só seria usado caso você quisesse retornar as varáveis tabuladas para uma outra variável e imprimir elas fora do corpo da função.

Exemplo sem return:

```
PL = 'PLACA'
MD = 'MODELO' 
VL = 'VALOR'

def imprimir_placa(PL,MD,VL): 
    titulos = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(PL,MD,VL))
    print(titulos)

imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL)
```

E esses valores do parâmetro da função não precisam receber o mesmo nome, ex:

```
PL = 'PLACA'
MD = 'MODELO'
VL = 'VALOR'

def imprimir_placa(x, y, z):
    titulos = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(x,y,z))    
    print(titulos)

imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL)
```

Agora usando o retorno, ele irá **obviamente** retornar algo para alguém, esse caso se cria uma variável que eu chamei de **retorno** e imprimi ela depois:

```
PL = 'PLACA'
MD = 'MODELO'
VL = 'VALOR'

def imprimir_placa(x, y, z):
    titulos = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(x,y,z))    
    return titulos

retorno = imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL)
print(retorno)
```

Ou se você não quiser passar esse valor pra ninguem, você pode imprimir direito a sua função, pois ela será um retorno de algo:

```
PL = 'PLACA'
MD = 'MODELO'
VL = 'VALOR'

def imprimir_placa(x, y, z):
    titulos = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(x,y,z))    
    return titulos

print(imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Aprendi bastante com as respostas.

Answer (score -1):

Se o que você quer é criar uma função que retorne os valores formatados, é simples, e primeiro vamos corrigir alguns pontos da sua função:

```
def imprimir_placa(PL, MD, VL):
    return = ('{} {:>20} {:>30}'.format(PL,MD,VL))
    titulos = imprimir_placa('PLACA', 'MODELO', 'VALOR')
    print(titulos)
```

1. Quando voce usa a instrucao `return`, qualquer código que venha em seguida será ignorado, pois o return vai retornar um valor para o local que a chamou e parar sua execução ali mesmo.
2. Ao usar o `return`, não se usa o sinal de `=` em seguida, a sintaxe do return é simplesmente `return x` (onde x pode ser qualquer variável, calculo, etc)
3. Voce está chamando sua função novamente dentro de si mesma e isso se chama recursão (conceito que vc verá mais a frente) e que sem uma instrução de parada pode causar um RecursionError, claro que com você não vai ocorrer pois o return vai parar a execução antes.

---

#### Uma possível solução:

```py
def gera_titulos(PL, MD, VL):  
    # retorna uma string formatada com os valores passados por parametro
    return "{} {:>20} {:>20}".format(PL, MD, VL)


def imprimir_placa():
    # chama a função passando os valores como parametro e em seguida
    # printa o retorno
    print(gera_titulos("PLACA", "MODELO", "VALOR"))


imprimir_placa()
```

Note que eu usei o retorno dessa função como parametro do `print`, mas também poderia armazenar em uma variável e utilizar em outros lugares do código. Assim como também poderia passar quaisquer outros três valores na chamada da função e ela formataria os mesmos da mesma forma.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Aprendi bastante com as respostas.